# Java process for authentication on Windows against AD (kerberos)

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

I'm aware I can call out to Active Directory and do queries provided I have a cleartext username and password. (I don't want to do that)

In VB, I can set authorisation levels by NT group - and the user doesn't have to enter their password nor, store it in a text file. (My understanding is that this has access to the Windows AD ticket).

How can I get the kerberos ticket from the user's logged in session in windows? (without asking for a username and password).

This appears to get there:
[Java and Kerberos authentication krb5.conf versus System.setProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431999/java-and-kerberos-authentication-krb5-conf-versus-system-setproperty)
But doesn't get the ticket.

(It is beginning to sound like I'll have to call the Win32 API with JNA to get the kerberos ticket - I'm hoping there is a simpler way.)

Comment: what are you trying to do with the ticket itself? Is it an option to generate tickets as needed using keytabs?

Comment: This is the first part of a series of questions. I'd like to pass the ticket to AD to get more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/index.html) one. It will guide your through the steps to obtain a service ticket for a specific server. Beware that the client machine and account have to part of the domain.

Comment: Any chance of updating the link?

Comment: @hawkeye Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/index.html
Java 11: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/introduction-jaas-and-java-gss-api-tutorials1.html
Java 17: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/introduction-jaas-and-java-gss-api-tutorials1.html